# Bash shell script for finding file size

Tags: linux, shell, filesize

Consider:

```
var=`ls -l | grep TestFile.txt | awk '{print $5}'`
```

I am able to read file size, but how does it work?

Comment: var=`ls -l | grep TestFile.txt | awk '{print $5}'` reverse quote is not visible here, when i check  -> ls -l | grep TestFile.txt  output is only file is displayed how come awk got the size also

Comment: Just as a side note, this seems like an awfully long-winded way to write `du`.

Comment: `stat -c %s TestFile.txt` would be a far superior approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, so basically you could divide it into 4 parts:

1. `ls -l`

List the current directory content (`-l` for long listing format)

2. `| grep TestFile.txt`

Pipe the result and look for the file you are interested in

3. `| awk '{print $5}`

Pipe the result to awk program which cuts (by using spaces as separator) the fifth column which happens to be the file size in this case (but this can be broken by spaces in the filename, for example)

4. var=`...`

The backquotes (**`**) enclose commands. The output of the commands gets stored in the var variable.

**NOTE**: You can get the file size directly by using `du -b TestFile.txt` or `stat -c %s TestFile.txt`

Comment: Thanks   i read in stack overflow and used du however it byte read b is not supported my board                 # du -b
du: invalid option -- 'b'
BusyBox v1.20.2 (2015-09-29 11:55:16 IST) multi-call binary.

Usage: du [-aHLdclsxk] [FILE]...

Comment: @Dam if redobot's answer indeed helped you, make sure to accept it (tick it as correct).

Comment: @Dam it seems that BusyBox's version of `du` doesn't support showing the file size in bytes.  Leave the `-b` option off (or substitute with `-k`) and it'll show file sizes in *kilobytes* instead.

Comment: looks like the BusyBox version is different from the GNU's version. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157817/why-are-du-some-options-not-available. As @IanMcLaird said you could use the other options (-k, -m or -h). This should be OK unless you would like to use the size in some mathematical operation.

Comment: @redobot Also note that `du` and `stat` can report two very different numbers in the case of sparse files - `stat` will report the same number that `ls -l` does, which is why it is probably the better answer in this case, while `du` will report the actual total disk space actually being used (although some versions of `du` have an `--apparent-size` or similar option).

Answer (score 4):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fmywiki.wooledge.org%2FParsingLs)

```
size=$( stat -c '%s' TestFile.txt )
```

Comment: Another one of those "*use the proper tool for the job*" scenarios... `ls` - list files, `stat` - file statistics. Clever names...

Comment: The link is broken (*"400 Bad Request"*). Perhaps add the *why* inline?